# Random line break at the end of a message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I'm making a bot for discord with discord.py. I have a command that generates a user id list of everyone on the server. It then selects a random person and asks if they want to play a game. The problem is that after the id it breaks the line. If you can help thank you.

```
    if message.content.startswith('plz mention'):
         open('ID.log', 'w').close()
         x = message.server.members
         for members in x:
              loggerID.info(members.id)
         games = ["Apex", "Rocket League", "Overwatch"]
         id = random.choice(open('ID.log').readlines())[32:]
         msg = '<@!%s> do you want to play %s' %(id ,random.choice(games))
         await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
```

Comment: Why are you reading the username from "ID.log" instead of using the built in functions to find users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that by using `id = random.choice(open('ID.log').readlines())[32:]` you get a line of the file, including the newline character(s) at the end.

Possible fix: The `str.rstrip()` method that removes trailing whitespace:

`id = random.choice(open('ID.log').readlines())[32:].rstrip()`

Answer (score 0):

Random characters be removed with either rsrtip() or with re.split

```
import re

.

fileread = open('file.txt').read().rstrip()
fixedlist = re.split(' |\s|\n', fileread)
```